# How do determine default C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you compile a package using `catkin_make`, what's the default C++ compiler used? I assumed it was g++, but I can't confirm this.

This is probably documented somewhere, but I can't find it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239852/how-do-determine-default-c++-compiler?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Detecting the compiler (as it's not so much *configured*, as it is *detected* (or at least *verified*)) is actually not something catkin does, but is a CMake affair. As such, you can use any of the traditional ways (setting `CC` and/or `CXX` env flags before invoking `catkin_make`, etc) to influence it.

I don't have a direct link to anything that completely explains how CMake does it, but some related pages:

- [cmake-toolchains](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html)
- [CMake Cross Compiling](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling)

After the compiler has been detected, CMake sets a nr of (internal) variables that store the bits and pieces of information it needs to work with that compiler. Some of those are documented on the [CMake Useful Variables](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Compilers_and_Tools) page.

Note that much (if not all) CMake documentation has migrated from the wiki to the generated docs at [cmake.org/documentation](https://cmake.org/documentation/).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1